# scikit-bio not working after installation

Tags: python, skbio

I have installed scikit-bio on my mac and when I run `python -m skbio.test`, I get the following error:

```
File "/macqiime/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/skbio/io/tests/test_util.py", line 17, in <module>
import httpretty
ImportError: No module named httpretty.
```

Could this be based on my `PATH`?

-macqiime is in the directory Users.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**:  Changed my answer to use conda instead of pip

Try executing:

```
conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/hargup httpretty
```

Comment: Presumably the OP is using anaconda. Will this work within anaconda?

Comment: I couldn't say.  I'm admittedly not familiar with anaconda.

Comment: @NBartley, thanks for the heads up. changed my answer to use conda instead of pip